# Can "who'd" be used as a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, relative-pronouns

I was doing this question: 
17. Although pharmaceutical companies that begun to produce the drug learned that taxol could be extracted from the bark of all species of yewr, they soon focused their attention on the Pacific yew.

A. NO CHANGE

B. who’d began producing

C. who begun producing

D. that began to produce

and I answered B. Why is it D? 
Isn't "that begun to produce the drug learned that taxol could be extracted from the bark of all species of yewr" an adjective clause. Why can't it be introduced by the relative pronoun *who*? Is it because of the *'d*?

Comment: It has nothing to do with *who*. The conjugation of *begin* requires *who began* or *who had begun*. The answers B and C reverse *began* and *begun*.

Comment: @PeterShor But the past perfect could not be used anyway, otherwise the main verb of the clause would need to match, with "had learned". Some might argue that matching here is not essential but to my rather old-fashioned mind proper English requires it.

Comment: @WS2: Whether you can use past perfect there is debatable. Whether you should use *who* as a relative pronoun for *company* is debatable. But in standard English, *who'd began* is undebatably wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes I agree. Both *who'd began* and *who begun* are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The "-'d" just means "had," so after it you would need the perfect form *begun,* not the simple past *began.*